# Need to add decimal column in existing table

Tags: magento2

I want to add new decimal column in sales_order_item table, I got this error when i run upgrade:setup command run. https://www.screencast.com/t/yGFPIhPJz

Is this below code correct? Please help me

```
$tableName = $setup->getTable('sales_order_item');
            if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true) {
                $columns = [
                    'extra_weight' => [
                        'type'      => [\Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DECIMAL, '10,2'],
                        'nullable'  => true,
                        'default'   => 0.00,
                        'comment'   => 'Item extra Weight'
                    ]
                ];
                $connection = $setup->getConnection();
                foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
                    $connection->addColumn($tableName, $name, $definition);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4):

Please change `type` parameter and add `length` parameter

```
$tableName = $setup->getTable('sales_order_item');
            if ($setup->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true) {
                $columns = [
                    'extra_weight' => [
                        'type'      => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DECIMAL,
                        'length'    => '10,2',
                        'nullable'  => true,
                        'default'   => 0.00,
                        'comment'   => 'Item extra Weight'
                    ]
                ];
                $connection = $setup->getConnection();
                foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
                    $connection->addColumn($tableName, $name, $definition);
                }
            }
```